# WebApi 5.2.7 causing error when passing array as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

After I updated Nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi from 5.2.3 to 5.2.7 I noticed this strange error

> The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The
>   inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for
>   this resource

Here is my controller action

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("show_many")]
        [ArrayInput("ids", Separator = ',')]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ShowMany(int[] ids)
        {

//code
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

I tried to remove ArrayInput attribute, but it appears that WebApi has problems understanding an array of ints.

Is this a know issue? How do I resolve it?

Comment: add [FromBody] int[] ids

Comment: He can't use [FromBody], because it is HttpGet.
I suppose, [FromQuery] has to be used.

Comment: [FromUri] worked for me

Comment: Yes, [FromUri] is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [FromUri] to

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ShowMany([FromUri] int[] ids)
```

solved the problem